# How do you declare variables in a ruby class file that are used for class declaration?

Tags: ruby

So I have a class file like:

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'json'
require 'plissken'

$obj_keys = [
  :id,
  :title,
  # ...
]

$attributes_struct = Struct.new(*$obj_keys)

module MyModule
  class MyClass
    extend Forwardable

    attr_reader :attributes
    delegate $obj_keys => :attributes

    def initialize(data={})
        @attributes = $attributes_struct(*data.values)
```

I don't want `$obj_keys` and `$attributes_struct` to be global variables, but I'm not sure how to declare them such that I can still have the same working logic.  How do I declare `$obj_keys` and `$attributes_struct` differently within this file?

Comment: I am sorry but it is unclear to me why you introduced the global variables and the delegate in the first place. Can you please explain how you want to use `MyClass` later on? What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: Can't you create a module and include them in your class?

Answer (score 1):

The variables logically belong inside the class anyway, so you could move them inside the class, as constants:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass

    OBJ_KEYS = [
        :id,
        :title,
        # ...
    ]

    ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT = Struct.new(OBJ_KEYS)
```

...

However, there is no real need for the separate obj_keys variable. Also, it's helpful to the reader of the class returned by Struct.new is capitalized (snake cased) like other classes. So this might be a better approach:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass

    Attributes = Struct.new(:id, :title)
```

You could always get information about the class from the runtime:

```
2.5.0 :001 > Attributes = Struct.new(:id, :title)
 => Attributes
2.5.0 :002 > Attributes.instance_methods(false)
 => [:title, :id=, :title=, :id]
2.5.0 :003 > attrs = Attributes.new(1, 'Hello')
 => #<struct Attributes id=1, title="Hello">
2.5.0 :004 > attrs.to_h
 => {:id=>1, :title=>"Hello"}
2.5.0 :005 > attrs.to_h.keys
 => [:id, :title]
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  Though I think I still need the `OBJ_KEYS` variable to do `delegate` logic.

Comment: The approach of using a `Struct` adds some complexity relative to just making the struct's attributes instance variables of the including class and using `attr_accessor` to create access methods for them. What is there about your situation that makes this worth the cost?

Comment: Good question.  I plan to store a json object from a response into `attributes`.  I think my reasoning is to separate the json object attributes from the ruby defined instance methods and other `attr_accessor`s so it's clear to me and other developers which attributes are a direct result of the json object and which are ruby attributes/helpers.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.